# Using built-in PHP server can't access localhost site that use custom domain name specified in etc/hosts

Tags: php, cmd, dns, hosts

Actually already asked my question in the title.
What I've done:

1. Installed PHP 8, and set path to it in env. var.
2. Changed file C:\Windows...\etc\hosts and added lines to it:

```
127.0.0.1   astrononeko.dev
127.0.0.1   www.astrononeko.dev
::1         astrononeko.dev
::1         www.astrononeko.dev
```

3. In cmd used

> ipconfig /flushdns

4. Then created directory C:\Projects\Web\php and file index.php. There is regular Hello world programm. Typed all the combinations listed below:

```
php -S localhost:80
php -S 127.0.0.1:80
php -S astrononeko.dev:80
php -S astrononeko.dev:4000
php -S www.astrononeko.dev:80
php -S www.astrononeko.dev:8000
php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

Through browser could access only by localhost. Command curl works on every listed domains, ping does not work on any if I specify the port

Using Windows 10 and PHP 8 only

When trying to adress by domain names, getting something like this

> [Wed Jun 15 15:46:19 2022] 127.0.0.1:60869 Accepted

> [Wed Jun 15 15:46:19 2022] 127.0.0.1:60868 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

> [Wed Jun 15 15:46:19 2022] 127.0.0.1:60868 Closing

Google refers it as httpS problem, but I checked both secured http and non-secured and actually there are problems around https when using another web-servers other than built-in PHP, like Apache, which I'm not using.

Will be really glad if you could answer my question if you know what is the problem!

Comment: [entire gTLD has been included in the HSTS preload-list; as a result, popular web browsers will only connect to a .dev webpage using HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dev) Choose another TLD for your test sites, I'd suggest .local

Comment: Wow, it has so simple solution. Didn't thought problem was in .dev. Thank you very much, it worked!
If you directly answer the question I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some time ago we started to change .dev for local development as .dev is a FQDN [now](https://get.dev/#:%7E:text=dev%3F-,.,interesting%20things%20that%20you%20build.). Why don't you try to change in your \etc\host to something like .test

```
127.0.0.1   astrononeko.test
127.0.0.1   www.astrononeko.test
::1         astrononeko.test
::1         www.astrononeko.test
```

Also be sure that your host file is readable by php.

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you.
Are there a lot of domains like this, which is reserved for internet-only(I mean not for local development)?